# Pairing of symbols in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a **text** and a **symbols** array , so current code does this :

Find a symbol from the text array and if next element is also a symbol, push both (the current symbol and the next element, which is also a symbol)with one / between them to a new array.(Make a symbol pair)

```
const text = [
  'aaaa', 'BTC',
  '08', '324',
  'ETH', '233',
  'yyyy', '30000',
  'XRP', 'xxxxxGG',
  'llll', '546',
  'BCH', 'LTC',
  'xxxyyy', '435',
  'XLM', 'DASH',
  'COIN'
];

const symbols = ['XLM','XTZ','BTC','DASH','COIN','ETH','LTC','BNB','BCH','XRP'];

//Return all the pair in text
   const set = new Set(symbols);
   const result = text.reduce((acc, curr, i, src) => {
     const next = src[i + 1];
       if (set.has(curr) && set.has(next)) acc.push(`${curr}/${next}`);
        return acc;
   }, []);


//output : 
//['BCH/LTC','XLM/DASH','DASH/COIN'],
```

But Here , there are 3 consecutive elements in text array , `'XLM', 'DASH' ,'COIN'`, and as you  see in the output ,it returns two pair of 3 consecutive symbols :`'XLM/DASH','DASH/COIN'`

I want to ignore it and if there is no other symbol after the third symbol, just return the first and second symbols in pairs

what i want from the text array :
`['BCH/LTC','XLM/DASH']`

And if there is a fourth symbol, return the third and fourth symbols in pairs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another approach is one adapted from the work you have done with `reduce`. The idea is to add a variable, which will track whether the last second pair matches the first pair of the immediate next match if it exists.

```js
const text = ['XLM', 'BTC','08', '324','ETH', '233','yyyy', '30000','XRP', 'xxxxxGG','llll', '546','BCH', 'LTC','xxxyyy', '435','XLM', 'DASH','COIN', 'ETH'];
const symbols = ['XLM', 'XTZ', 'BTC', 'DASH', 'COIN', 'ETH', 'LTC', 'BNB', 'BCH', 'XRP'];


let lastSecondPairI = -1; // must not be a index in first iteration
const set = new Set(symbols);
const result = text.reduce((acc, curr, i, src) => {
    const next = src[i + 1];
    if (set.has(curr) && set.has(next)){  
        // check if it does not match the current element (by i)
        if(lastSecondPairI !== i){
          acc.push(`${curr}/${next}`); 
          // update the value every time there's not a match
          lastSecondPairI = i+1; 
        }
    }
    return acc;
}, []);

console.log(result)
```

Comment: It doesn't work when the zero and first element are pairs `const text = ['BTC', 'XLM','08,...'`

Comment: What's the expected output and what you're getting?

Comment: returns empty array and ignore symbols , As if there is no symbol in the array

Comment: I didn't get why in this case `'[BTC', 'XLM',...` should return empty since both are present in symbols

Comment: Your code works except when the text[0] and text[1] are symbols

Comment: Ooh, you're right on point. Actually, fix it by changing: let `lastSecondPairI = 0;` to `-1` (or other negative value)

Answer (score 1):

Try using `for` loop

```js
const text = [
  'aaaa', 'BTC',
  '08', '324',
  'ETH', '233',
  'yyyy', '30000',
  'XRP', 'xxxxxGG',
  'llll', '546',
  'BCH', 'LTC',
  'xxxyyy', '435',
  'XLM', 'DASH',
  'COIN'
];


const symbols = ['XLM', 'XTZ', 'BTC', 'DASH', 'COIN', 'ETH', 'LTC', 'BNB', 'BCH', 'XRP'];

//Return all the pair in text
const set = new Set(symbols);

let result = []
for (let i = 0; i < text.length; i += 2) {
  let curr = text[i], next = text[i + 1];
  if (set.has(curr) && set.has(next)) {
    result.push(`${curr}/${next}`)
  }
}

console.log(result)
```